# Stroke-linecap round with polyline

Tags: svg

I am very new to SVG and I am having some trouble with my SVG polyline. I am trying to round the top of the arrow below with `stroke-linecap="round"` and `stroke-linejoin="round"` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 23.7 44.5" enable-background="new 0 0 23.7 44.5" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon points="22.3,44.5 23.7,43.1 2.8,22.3 23.7,1.4 22.3,0 0,22.3 " stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified a stroke so no stroke is drawn (try stroke="red") . The polygon is actually visible because it is filled that way. What you really want are two lines stroked. Something like this...

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 200">
  <polyline points="23,43.8 3.5,22.3 22.3,3 " stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. That's exactly what I wanted, thanks!